# Get the last row that was left outside of a timeframed SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there a way to write a SQL query with a time-frame condition to include the *latest* row that is outside of the time-frame (besides solutions like counting the size of the result set and querying for the size+1, etc.) ?

Lets say I have a table `A`, which holds timestamped value changes.

I want to query for all the changes in the last 24 hours (assume that the time when the query was ran on 2019-08-08 00:00:00) - how do I include the last row that isn't included in 24-hours interval, i.e., row #2 (assuming I don't know when it occurred):

```
CREATE TABLE A(`timeframe` datetime, `value` int);

INSERT INTO A 
(`timeframe`, `value`)
VALUES
('2019-06-08 18:00:00', 10),
('2019-06-09 02:00:00', 20),
('2019-07-08 17:00:00', 50),
('2019-07-08 19:00:00', 10),
('2019-07-09 01:35:00', 30),
('2019-07-09 02:00:00', 40);

| timestamp        | value |
|------------------|-------|
| 2019-08-06 15:00 | 10    |
| 2019-08-06 23:00 | 20    |
| 2019-08-07 14:00 | 50    |
| 2019-08-07 16:00 | 10    |
| 2019-08-07 22:35 | 30    |
| 2019-08-07 23:00 | 40    |

SELECT value 
     , time 
  FROM A 
 WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

The result set should include the value changes in last day (rows #3-#6) and the latest row outside the timeframe - row #2.

I'm looking for a generic solution, as the time-frame can changed.

Comment: @Strawberry Not sure I understand, the example I provided isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this below script where first part will return records from last 24 hours and the second script will return the latest row before 24 hours. Union all of result should give your expected output-

```
SELECT value,timeframe 
FROM A 
WHERE timeframe >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT value,timeframe 
    FROM A 
    WHERE timeframe < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ORDER BY timeframe DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have older rows you can do:

```
SELECT value, time 
FROM A 
WHERE a.time >= (SELECT MAX(a2.time)
                 FROM A a2
                 WHERE a2.time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                );
```

If there are no older rows, you have a bit of a challenge dealing with `NULL`.  This is one place where `ALL` is handy:

```
SELECT value, time 
FROM A 
WHERE a.time >= ALL (SELECT a2.time
                     FROM A a2
                     WHERE a2.time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                    );
```